# Cannot insert to database through console app

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, console-application, executenonquery

I am trying to write an insert method in a C# console application. I have set a breakpoint and it does hit `ExecuteNonQuery`, however, after stepping through it just hangs there and control does not seem to return back to the application.  When I perform a read action on the database it works perfectly.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.dbDevices (ipAddress) VALUES (@value)", connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@value", "SUCCESS");
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I have also checked the active connections to the database and it says that it is awaiting command.

```
.Net SqlClient Data Provider     5720       AWAITING COMMAND
```

More information can be provided if needed.

Comment: Have you compared the working and non-working queries with SQL Profiler?

Comment: Do you have a transaction scope around this block? ... and what number is returned by `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's related but you're passing parameter value using `deprecated` method. I recommend using `AddWithValue` method. So it's either:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", "SUCCESS");
```

or

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", "SUCCESS"));
```

Comment: I realised this and have changed it, thanks for the advice though : )

Comment: @Johnathon64 Did it solve your problem or you're still getting the same error?

Comment: I'm not actually getting any errors, it just hangs there

Comment: @Johnathon64 You could be getting timeouts if your table is locked for some reason or if your transaction log is full.

Comment: I just did a DBCC OPENTRAN on SSMS and it said no active open transactions